# Why does memory usage increase on redeploying a web application?

Tags: tomcat

Is it true that when I redeploy a web application memory usage will increase in Tomcat ? I'm reading it is because classloader and the objects it created cannot be recycled and they are stored in the permanent heap generation space of the JVM. What does this mean ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find an explanation of class loader leaks here:

http://code.google.com/p/arit/wiki/GettingStarted